# Show that forms of degree d in $\Gamma$ form a finite dimensional vector space - Fulton 4.9

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$ and
$$ \Gamma = k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]/I. $$
Show that the set of forms of degree d in $\Gamma$ form a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$.

Current thoughts: can one somehow connect this to projective Nullstellensatz to use that
$\mathbb{V}(I)=\varnothing$ if and only if $I$ contains all forms of degree $\geq N$ for some $N$. In that case, could one somehow connect it to corollary 4 on page 11 in Fulton which says that $V(I)$ is finite for an ideal $I$ if and only if $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I$ is finite-dimensional over $k$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are kind of missing the point here. Try the case when $I=0$.

Comment: Don't the monomials of degree $d$ form a finite basis?